# MS Access Disk or Network Error 3043

Tags: ms-access

I am searching for a solution for the dreaded 3043 error in MS Access.

One of my clients is running a splitted FE/BE application, about 6-7 users, BE size about 100 MB. In the last weeks the error is coming more and more often. After closing the DB and reopening everything is just fine. But the data entered in the currently open form is lost. At first this happened once a day, now every 90 minutes - which is very annoying for the users.

The web is full of possible solutions and workarounds, but nothing really works or helps to clear this issue.

Comment: What OS is hosting the backend file and what OS(s) are running your frontend? Do all the workstations have this problem and do they all show this behavior at the same time? Any reason to believe it might be related to the lock file? Do some machines have more than one entry in the lock file when this occurs (you can read the lock file with Notepad++)?

Comment: Today I've been on site at the client and found out the following: the station with the highest occurence (by far) of the problem is a Win7 64 bit AND (here comes) offline folders enabled. I turned off the offline thing and hopes this will make things better.

Comment: Are there other file servers available? One quick test would be to move the back end to a different server. I've seen this fix problems like this, usually because the network settings were different (the most likely candidate is the NetBIOS over TCP/IP setting, actually).

Comment: No other servers there. But thanks for the tip with NetBIOS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen this is usually an intermittently flaky network.  Trouble is there can be many causes.    You've probably already seen my [Corrupt Microsoft Access MDBs FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm) page.  As far as I know that page and the linked pages are the most exhaustive collection of possible causes of corruption.

The biggest problem will likely be convincing the IT department that they have a problem.  They, and many ignorant folks on Stack Overflow, will mutter bad words against Access when it's really a hard to find problem on the network.

Comment: I think it is fair for the IT Dept. to complain about an application that is network based and unable to handle some network fluctuation. If it is happening a lot, sure that needs to be fix on the network side, but at the same time, some durability should be built into the application. Many applications do a much better job at handling this. If they didn't the Internet like we know it wouldn't exist. If your connection passes through the Internet (maybe in a VPN tunnel), expect the occasional problems.

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the backend to SQL Server 2008 Express and then use ODBC linked tables to connect the front end to the backend. You'll need to recode certain portions of the frontend to make it work with SQL Server linked tables. (I'm not going to elaborate as it would be to address that in a separate question.)

Microsoft has a free tool you can use to convert your database backend to SQL Server: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5abe098d-c7e1-46c6-994a-09a2856eef0b&displaylang=en

I suppose this isn't the solution you're looking for but I think it's the most sure-fire way to eliminate the error your getting. However, if you truly have network stability issues, you will likely have problems with SQL Server as well although I think it is slightly more forgiving when it comes to network hiccups because of it's architecture.

Comment: In this project we're talking about 100+ forms, 200 queries, 70 reports and about 20k LOC. This is too much to just convert an recode a little. But the switch to SQL Server is on the roadmap for later.

Comment: This is a ridiculous answer. The problem is completely solvable (assuming a non-wireless environment, of course), so there's no reason for such a Draconian response. -1